# Java application: Getting input before running

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

```
public class checkUsernames extends JFrame {
private static JTextArea textArea1;
private static JButton button1;
private static JScrollPane scrollPane1;
private static JTextField textField1;
private static JPasswordField passwordField1;
private static JLabel label3;
private static JButton button2;
private static JLabel label1;
private static JLabel label2;

public checkUsernames() {
    initComponents();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nimbus isn't available");
        }

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                checkUsernames GUI = new checkUsernames();
                GUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                GUI.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        String username = textField1.toString();
        String password = passwordField1.toString();
```

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`

`checkUsernames` is the only class.  When I try to run the application the program executes further (proceeding without String username & String password) without waiting for input. How can I fix this?

Comment: invokeLater does exactly that by running the GUI on a separate thread.  If you want the GUI to display before anything else happens, you should be able to do that by starting it on the main thread.

Comment: Ah. I put the `checkUsernames GUI = new checkUsernames();
                GUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                GUI.setVisible(true);
` 
inside the main method and out of invokeLater.  How can I make the program wait for input? It executes everything in the main method lol.  I feel so stupid right now...

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) like I posted back in your [last thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971882/jformdesigner-design-it-wont-display/5972358#5972358).  Note that my answer was several minutes later because I had to turn it into an SSCCE (before I was prepared to make comments).

Comment: Apologies Andrew, I was rushing too fast I should have stopped and waited.  Thanks for the link I will try to do that on future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the code execution to stop while waiting for input, make the `JFrame` a modal `JDialog` or `JOptionPane` instead.

Answer (score 1):

None of your private static members appear to be initialized at all.  You won't get past the NullPointerException until you initialize each and every object you create before you use it.

I have no idea what you're talking about.  You have to do something like this for all those objects:

```
private static JTextArea textArea1 = new JTextArea();
```

You aren't entering a username or password; you're creating a text area UI element that can accept them when you do enter them.

Comment: That's kinda the problem.  When I execute the application I'm supposed to enter in my username & password.  But it proceeds without me entering any information:\

Answer (score 1):

Well **invokeLater** will invoke the code later. It dosent gurantee textfield1.toString() to execute **after** checkUserNames()

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use [SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeAndWait%28java.lang.Runnable%29) instead? This seems to solve your problem immediately.

Here is the simple example:

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class InvokeAndWaitExample {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable () {
                public void run () {
                    System.out.println("Hello World on " + Thread.currentThread());
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Finished on " + Thread.currentThread());
    }
}
```