# how to call a public class to display gui in java using jformdesigner

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe

I wish to display my gui in the main method however it doesn't seem to do so...
I've used the suggestion here:
[jformdesigner design it won't display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971882/jformdesigner-design-it-wont-display)

But that did not work,

My error at the moment is that eclipse is suggesting I need to create a method called setDefaultCloseOperation which is already defined in the class and the same for the setvisible.

"The method setDefaultCloseOperation(int) is undefined for the type bmicalc

The method setVisible(boolean) is undefined for the type bmicalc"

main method:

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class iu {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            bmicalc GUI = new bmicalc();
            GUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            GUI.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
class bmicalc extends JFrame{

public bmicalc() {
    initComponents();

}
private void initComponents() {
    JFrame bmiCalculatorFrame = new JFrame();
    {
        bmiCalculatorFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        bmiCalculatorFrame.setTitle("BMI Calculator");
        Container bmiCalculatorFrameContentPane = bmiCalculatorFrame.getContentPane();
        bmiCalculatorFrameContentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    }
}}}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `bmicalc` class should extend `JFrame`, but it is not. `setDefaultCloseOperation` and `setVisible` methods belong to `JFrame`.

Also, it is not very clear, but it looks like the JFormDesigner generated another `JFrame`.

**EDIT:**

Here is a example of `JFrame` generated by JFormDesigner:

```
public class TestFrame extends JFrame {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    TestFrame frame = new TestFrame();
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
     }

    public TestFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        // JFormDesigner - Component initialization - DO NOT MODIFY  //GEN-BEGIN:initComponents

        //======== this ========
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new FormLayout(
            "default",
            "default"));
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(getOwner());
        // JFormDesigner - End of component initialization  //GEN-END:initComponents
    }

    // JFormDesigner - Variables declaration - DO NOT MODIFY  //GEN-BEGIN:variables
    // JFormDesigner - End of variables declaration  //GEN-END:variables
}
```

**EDIT - according to the last question edit**

To address your compilation issues see the snippet below. However, it is not clear what are you trying to achieve with `JFrame bmiCalculatorFrame`.

```
class bmicalc extends JFrame{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            bmicalc GUI = new bmicalc();
            GUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            GUI.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

public bmicalc() {
    initComponents();

}

private void initComponents() {
    //............
}
}
```

Comment: Another user told me that I had already created a JFrame .` private void initComponents() {


   JFrame bmiCalculatorFrame = new JFrame();` and had stated it cannot 'have a' and 'is-a' JFrame

Comment: I've added the extension but if I am going about this the wrong way can you please suggest an alternative way to display the Frame

Comment: @Banned not sure how you jfd file looks like, check out an empty `JFrame` I added in my last edit.

Comment: Strangely the FormLayout is not being initialised in my JFD?

Comment: @Banned see my last edit with regards to the compilation issues you have.

Comment: This worked however it has caused an adverse effect on the final output as now I see this: http://i48.tinypic.com/20prk0w.png when it is supposed to show: http://i50.tinypic.com/2w6th01.png

Comment: The bmiCalculatorFrame is the frame that was made by JFD which I presumed I was supposed to use?

Comment: @Banned I assume you should show the frame you created. It looks like you have two frames - one generated by JFD and one you created as a wrapper. Just add `main()` to the frame generated by JFD, no need to wrap it in another frame.

Comment: doing so causes many more problems for some reason which I cannot figure out, here is a pastie link with the FULL code. http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=6nzcEQEF                              If you paste that in your IDE it will work, any help in this is greatly appreciated

Comment: @Banned Is that code auto generated by JFD? The generated file is messed up. It is very easy to fix. Can you paste your jfd file?

Comment: Thanks Max, I have solved the issue it seems that I was making the BMICalculatorFrame separately from the other one and the way to fix it would be change the name of BMICalculatorFrame to this which would make it work. Thanks once again though