# Java + JFormDesigner + Empty JFrame

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, jform-designer

I've decided to give a try to **JFormDesigner** to design my application user interface.
I've set up my GUI through the IntelliJ Idea plugin and obtained the usual auto-generated code:

```
package dataParser.View;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import net.miginfocom.swing.*;

public class MainView extends JFrame {
    public MainView() {
        initComponents();
        pack();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
    // JFormDesigner - Component initialization - DO NOT MODIFY  //GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("dataParser.Resources.strings");
    mainFrame = new JFrame();
    tabbedPanel = new JTabbedPane();
    apachePanel = new JSplitPane();
    leftSideSplitPanel = new JSplitPane();
    mySqlPanel = new JPanel();
    mySqlPortLabel = new JLabel();
    mySqlPortTextField = new JFormattedTextField();
    usernameField = new JLabel();
    usernameTextField = new JFormattedTextField();
    passwordLabel = new JLabel();
    passwordTextField = new JFormattedTextField();
    mySqlApplyButton = new JButton();
    mySqlTestButton = new JButton();
    servicesPanel = new JPanel();
    apacheButton = new JButton();
    mySqlButton = new JButton();
    rightSidePanel = new JSplitPane();
    controlUnitPanel = new JPanel();
    cuIpLabel = new JLabel();
    cuIpTextField = new JFormattedTextField();
    cuPortLabel = new JLabel();
    cuPortTextField = new JFormattedTextField();
    cuApplyButton = new JButton();
    cutestButton = new JButton();
    logScrollPanel = new JScrollPane();
    scrollTextPanel = new JTextPane();
    panel10 = new JPanel();

    //======== mainFrame ========
    {
        mainFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setResizable(false);
        Container mainFrameContentPane = mainFrame.getContentPane();

        //======== tabbedPanel ========
        {

            //======== apachePanel ========
            {
                apachePanel.setResizeWeight(0.4);

                //======== leftSideSplitPanel ========
                {
                    leftSideSplitPanel.setOrientation(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
                    leftSideSplitPanel.setResizeWeight(0.5);

                    //======== mySqlPanel ========
                    {
                        mySqlPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
                        mySqlPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(LineBorder.createBlackLineBorder(), bundle.getString("MainView.mySqlPanel.border"), TitledBorder.CENTER, TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION,
                            new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11)));
                        mySqlPanel.setLayout(new MigLayout(
                            "fill,insets panel,hidemode 3",
                            // columns
                            "[fill]" +
                            "[fill]",
                            // rows
                            "[]" +
                            "[]" +
                            "[]" +
                            "[]"));

                        //---- mySqlPortLabel ----
                        mySqlPortLabel.setText(bundle.getString("MainView.mySqlPortLabel.text"));
                        mySqlPortLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                        mySqlPanel.add(mySqlPortLabel, "cell 0 0,alignx center,growx 0");

                        //---- mySqlPortTextField ----
                        mySqlPortTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                        mySqlPanel.add(mySqlPortTextField, "cell 1 0");

                        //---- usernameField ----
                        usernameField.setText(bundle.getString("MainView.usernameField.text"));
                        usernameField.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                        mySqlPanel.add(usernameField, "cell 0 1,alignx center,growx 0");

                        //---- usernameTextField ----
                        usernameTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                        mySqlPanel.add(usernameTextField, "cell 1 1");

                        //---- passwordLabel ----
                        passwordLabel.setText(bundle.getString("MainView.passwordLabel.text"));
                        passwordLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                        mySqlPanel.add(passwordLabel, "cell 0 2,alignx center,growx 0");

                        //---- passwordTextField ----
                        passwordTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                        mySqlPanel.add(passwordTextField, "cell 1 2");

                        //---- mySqlApplyButton ----
                        mySqlApplyButton.setText(bundle.getString("MainView.mySqlApplyButton.text"));
                        mySqlPanel.add(mySqlApplyButton, "cell 0 3");

                        //---- mySqlTestButton ----
                        mySqlTestButton.setText(bundle.getString("MainView.mySqlTestButton.text"));
                        mySqlPanel.add(mySqlTestButton, "cell 1 3");
                    }
                    leftSideSplitPanel.setTopComponent(mySqlPanel);

                    //======== servicesPanel ========
                    {
                        servicesPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
                        servicesPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(LineBorder.createBlackLineBorder(), bundle.getString("MainView.servicesPanel.border"), TitledBorder.CENTER, TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION,
                            new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11)));
                        servicesPanel.setLayout(new MigLayout(
                            "fill,hidemode 3",
                            // columns
                            "[fill]",
                            // rows
                            "[]" +
                            "[]"));

                        //---- apacheButton ----
                        apacheButton.setText(bundle.getString("MainView.apacheButton.text"));
                        servicesPanel.add(apacheButton, "cell 0 0");

                        //---- mySqlButton ----
                        mySqlButton.setText(bundle.getString("MainView.mySqlButton.text"));
                        servicesPanel.add(mySqlButton, "cell 0 1");
                    }
                    leftSideSplitPanel.setBottomComponent(servicesPanel);
                }
                apachePanel.setLeftComponent(leftSideSplitPanel);

                //======== rightSidePanel ========
                {
                    rightSidePanel.setOrientation(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
                    rightSidePanel.setResizeWeight(0.5);

                    //======== controlUnitPanel ========
                    {
                        controlUnitPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
                        controlUnitPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(LineBorder.createBlackLineBorder(), bundle.getString("MainView.controlUnitPanel.border"), TitledBorder.CENTER, TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION,
                            new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11)));
                        controlUnitPanel.setLayout(new MigLayout(
                            "fill,insets panel,hidemode 3",
                            // columns
                            "[fill]" +
                            "[fill]",
                            // rows
                            "[]" +
                            "[]" +
                            "[]"));

                        //---- cuIpLabel ----
                        cuIpLabel.setText(bundle.getString("MainView.cuIpLabel.text"));
                        cuIpLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                        controlUnitPanel.add(cuIpLabel, "cell 0 0,alignx center,growx 0");

                        //---- cuIpTextField ----
                        cuIpTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                        controlUnitPanel.add(cuIpTextField, "cell 1 0");

                        //---- cuPortLabel ----
                        cuPortLabel.setText(bundle.getString("MainView.cuPortLabel.text"));
                        cuPortLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                        controlUnitPanel.add(cuPortLabel, "cell 0 1,alignx center,growx 0");

                        //---- cuPortTextField ----
                        cuPortTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                        controlUnitPanel.add(cuPortTextField, "cell 1 1");

                        //---- cuApplyButton ----
                        cuApplyButton.setText(bundle.getString("MainView.cuApplyButton.text"));
                        controlUnitPanel.add(cuApplyButton, "cell 0 2");

                        //---- cutestButton ----
                        cutestButton.setText(bundle.getString("MainView.cutestButton.text"));
                        controlUnitPanel.add(cutestButton, "cell 1 2");
                    }
                    rightSidePanel.setTopComponent(controlUnitPanel);

                    //======== logScrollPanel ========
                    {
                        logScrollPanel.setViewportView(scrollTextPanel);
                    }
                    rightSidePanel.setBottomComponent(logScrollPanel);
                }
                apachePanel.setRightComponent(rightSidePanel);
            }
            tabbedPanel.addTab(bundle.getString("MainView.apachePanel.tab.title"), apachePanel);

            //======== panel10 ========
            {
                panel10.setLayout(new MigLayout(
                    "fill,hidemode 3",
                    // columns
                    "[fill]" +
                    "[fill]",
                    // rows
                    "[]" +
                    "[]" +
                    "[]"));
            }
            tabbedPanel.addTab(bundle.getString("MainView.panel10.tab.title"), panel10);
        }

        GroupLayout mainFrameContentPaneLayout = new GroupLayout(mainFrameContentPane);
        mainFrameContentPane.setLayout(mainFrameContentPaneLayout);
        mainFrameContentPaneLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            mainFrameContentPaneLayout.createParallelGroup()
                .addGroup(mainFrameContentPaneLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(tabbedPanel)
                    .addContainerGap())
        );
        mainFrameContentPaneLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            mainFrameContentPaneLayout.createParallelGroup()
                .addGroup(mainFrameContentPaneLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(tabbedPanel)
                    .addContainerGap())
        );
        mainFrame.setSize(655, 520);
        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
    // JFormDesigner - End of component initialization  //GEN-END:initComponents
}
    }

    // JFormDesigner - Variables declaration - DO NOT MODIFY
        private JFrame mainFrame;
        private JTabbedPane tabbedPanel;
        private JSplitPane apachePanel;
        private JSplitPane leftSideSplitPanel;
        private JPanel mySqlPanel;
        private JLabel mySqlPortLabel;
        private JFormattedTextField mySqlPortTextField;
        private JLabel usernameField;
        private JFormattedTextField usernameTextField;
        private JLabel passwordLabel;
        private JFormattedTextField passwordTextField;
        private JButton mySqlApplyButton;
        private JButton mySqlTestButton;
        private JPanel servicesPanel;
        private JButton apacheButton;
        private JButton mySqlButton;
        private JSplitPane rightSidePanel;
        private JPanel controlUnitPanel;
        private JLabel cuIpLabel;
        private JFormattedTextField cuIpTextField;
        private JLabel cuPortLabel;
        private JFormattedTextField cuPortTextField;
        private JButton cuApplyButton;
        private JButton cutestButton;
        private JScrollPane logScrollPanel;
        private JTextPane scrollTextPanel;
        private JPanel panel10;
   }
```

After that, in my *MainClass*, I've set up my main method like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    [...]

    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        MainView GUI = new MainView();
        GUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        GUI.setVisible(true);
    });
}
```

Nevertheless, when I launch my application, I can only see this

[image: At loading...]

and then this one when I enlarge the JFrame.

[image: After the resize...]

I've looked around similar questions, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971882/jformdesigner-design-it-wont-display), but I can't get around this problem. Any hints?
Thank you!

**EDIT**

Adding

```
this.setContentPane(this.tabbedPanel);
```

at the end of the auto-generated *initComponents()* method I'm finally seeing something similar to the thing I've designed with said plugin. Still, I don't think that I should modify that method, when it clearly says:
**// JFormDesigner - Component initialization - DO NOT MODIFY**

Moreover, this is what I see

[image: Old style]

when I should look at this:

[image: New style]

Comment: shall you share your code

Comment: Question updated.